# Spring Batch -Validating number of records

Tags: spring-batch

I am a newbie to Springbatch and trying to achieve the following:
We have a file with Header, Body and Footer records, where footer consists the total number of  lines that are supposed to be in the file.
Is there a way where I can validate the number of records in the input file with the number in the footer and throw an exception using Spring batch, if they dont match?

Answer (score 3):

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612355/spring-batch-reading-multiple-line-log-message/19629450#19629450) answer as base.
In your own reader you can manually manage item/footer reading delegating to standard `ItemProcessor` every normal line, but manage directly the footer check condition; using a `StepListener` in your reader you can access the total count of read object.

I hope I was clear, English is not my native language.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bellabax. But I am trying to handle the footer and detail message like this:<property name="tokenizers">
   <map>
    <entry key="02*" value-ref="DetailTokenizer" />
    <entry key="99*" value-ref="FooterTokenizer" />
   </map>
  </property>
  <property name="fieldSetMappers">
   <map>
    <entry key="02*" value-ref="DetailItemMapper" />
    <entry key="99*" value-ref="FooterMapper" />
   </map>
  </property>                                                                 Do you think I should still be implementing a custom Reader?Can I just create a custom Processor

Comment: Can I just create a custom Processor and access the counts there?

Comment: You can write a custom reader as well as a custom processor, your choice