# How to read complex input pattern using SPring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a situation where it is require to parse complex flat file, each record scatter to multiple lines as shown below. 

`BFT      ICVMORDR1400210IJ5                              *P*
00800RRJNZM  1EK19 1EL      *****    101
00800RRJNZM  *******************   5 201
00800RRJNZM  *******************   5 202
00800RRJNZM  *******************   5 203
00800RRJNZM  *******************   5 204
00800RRJNZM  *******************   5 205
00800RRJNZM  ******************    5 206
00800RRJNZM  ******************    5 301
00800RRJNZM  ******************    5 302
00800RRJNZM  ******************    59401`

I have header line for file, and detailed record was scatters to 4 different types of records like 100,200,300,400 series at the end. How to parse this complex using Spring Batch.

Comment: hi @vinay - can you give your input file format with two lines of example. It is possible to read the file and map it using fix length mapper. Using different processor configuration you can do what ever you want to. Just give some hi-lights like -

Comment: What is the length of row ? first param min/max length , second param min max length and so on .. and if you have the model class for the input to map with , then display it here. it will help to answer your question

Comment: The entire records scatter to multiple lines, which can be 11 to 15 lines, but the record type define what is end line in the given record.Every line is 80 character length, but first line is master record which end with 100 or 101 or .. and second line and few lines by 200 and 3rd type is 300 series and 4th type is 400 series ....

Comment: I think you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612355/spring-batch-reading-multiple-line-log-message as starting point.

Comment: not sure about how to read multiple lines as one record

Answer (score 0):

to read one line as records - you can use below configuration in ur xml file --

```
  <bean id="customlineTokenizer"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer">
        <property name="columns" value="1-5,6-10" />
        <property name="names" value="firstname,lastname" />
    </bean>

        <bean id="customFieldSetMapper" class="com.mkyong.model.ReportFieldSetMapper" />


<bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="strict" value="false" />
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:report1" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer" ref="customlineTokenizer" />
            <property name="fieldSetMapper" ref="customFieldSetMapper" >
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>
```

Comment: It is not one line.. my requirement the single record scattered to multiple lines..